# Remote desktop into an Android device

Tags: remote-access

Is it possible, or is there an app, to remote desktop into an android device from a Windows or Mac computer?  I would like to be able to see and control the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching Google Play, there's a bunch of them.

One I've successfully used (and it doesn't require rooting to device) is [VMLite VNC server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vmlite.vncserver).